# Uncaught TypeError: app.whenReady() / app.on("ready"). Electron 15.1.0

Tags: electron

When the application is launched, the following problems occur.

[Screenshot of app.whenReady function error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AsIl.png)

```
app.whenReady().then(createWindow)
```

[Screenshot of app.on('ready') function error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM32P.png)

```
app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

```js
// index.js

const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) { // eslint-disable-line global-require
  app.quit();
}

let mainWindow

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true
    }
  });

  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));

  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

// package.json

{
 "name": "demo-app",
 "productName": "demo-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My Electron application description",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "publish": "electron-forge publish",
        "lint": "echo \"No linting configured\""
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": {
        "name": "test",
        "email": "test@test.com"
      },
      "license": "MIT",
      "config": {
        "forge": {
          "packagerConfig": {},
          "makers": [
            {
              "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
              "config": {
                "name": "tutorial_app_remote"
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
              "platforms": [
                "darwin"
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
              "config": {}
            },
            {
              "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
              "config": {}
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.61",
        "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.61",
        "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.61",
        "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.61",
        "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.61",
        "electron": "^15.1.0",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.13"
      }
    }
```

```html
// index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p>Welcome to your Electron application.</p>
  <script type="module" src="index.js">
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Description

Application was built, using yarn create command and has all default functions and properties to run demo app. Two methods described above were checked that return the same error results.

I've also faced the problem with require is not defined, that was solved by adding false flag to the contextIsolation property of application window's webPreferences (IMHO can be useful for someone).

Comment: I've checked your code in Electron fiddle and it's working...
How do start your app, npm script, command line ?

Comment: yarn start / npm run start commands from the Webstorm IDE terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You should read a little bit more the Electron doc...
What I've checked was your `main.js` (`**index.js**` in your case).
BUT the problem is your `**index.html**` which is indicating also **index.js as a ressource script.**
Rename your index.js as main.js and do it also in your package.json : that your main process.
And obviuosly there will be no more error
After you will be able to put what you need in the renderer of index.html --> index.js.